# Trying to install manjaro and have a problem with allocating of the disk free space

Tags: installation, lvm, manjaro, btrfs

I'm trying to install manjaro on laptop with oem windows 10 on board, I do it using 
manjaro architect cli installer. I've created LVM, parted logical volumes, made luks on LVM, formatted partitions to btrfs and mounted it. When I moved next and began installing DE I caught the error:

```
checking available disk space...
error: Partition /mnt too full: 1333620 blocks needed, 0 blocks free
error: not enough free disk space
error: failed to commit transaction (not enough free disk space)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
==> ERROR: Failed to install packages to new root
```

Then I type df -hT and see this:

```
Filesystem                       Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev                              devtmpfs  6.8G     0  6.8G   0% /dev
run                              tmpfs     6.9G  101M  6.8G   2% /run
/dev/sdb1                        iso9660   2.7G  2.7G     0 100% /run/miso/bootmnt
cowspace                         tmpfs     256M     0  256M   0% /run/miso/cowspace
overlay_root                     tmpfs      11G  189M   11G   2% /run/miso/overlay_root
/dev/loop0                       squashfs   21M   21M     0 100% /run/miso/sfs/livefs
/dev/loop1                       squashfs  457M  457M     0 100% /run/miso/sfs/mhwdfs
/dev/loop2                       squashfs  1.6G  1.6G     0 100% /run/miso/sfs/desktopfs
/dev/loop3                       squashfs  592M  592M     0 100% /run/miso/sfs/rootfs
overlay                          overlay    11G  189M   11G   2% /
tmpfs                            tmpfs     6.9G  121M  6.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            tmpfs     6.9G     0  6.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                            tmpfs     6.9G   48M  6.8G   1% /tmp
tmpfs                            tmpfs     6.9G  2.3M  6.9G   1% /etc/pacman.d/gnupg
tmpfs                            tmpfs     1.4G   12K  1.4G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/mapper/vg--default-lv--root btrfs     162G  1.1G     0 100% /mnt
/dev/mapper/crypto-home          btrfs      60G  3.4M   60G   1% /mnt/home
/dev/mapper/crypto-project       btrfs      40G  3.4M   40G   1% /mnt/home/project
/dev/nvme0n1p4                   fuseblk   200G   20G  181G  10% /mnt/windows
/dev/nvme0n1p7                   vfat       99M   512   99M   1% /mnt/boot/efi
```

What is wrong with the row?

```
/dev/mapper/vg--default-lv--root btrfs     162G  1.1G     0 100% /mnt
```

How can it be so - Use% 100% and Avail 0, but only 1.1G is used from 162G?

Comment: My investigation shows what the btrfs formatted luks over lvm probably are not related with strange allocating of the disk, because "clear" btrfs has the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to manually unmount and remount the filesystem before installing packages. Possibly, closing and reopening the btrfs volume is also necessary. If you run into the issue while packages are being installed, you can do the mount/remount and then just redo the package installation step without formatting.

Previously I wrote the following, however it did not help in a recent install:

I ran into the same issue. This is some sort of bug in btrfs. I stumbled upon a workaround. After manually creating a file and writing to it (`touch /mnt/temp`, `dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/temp bs=1M count=1000`), `df` began to report correct available space and I was able to resume the installation.

P.S. I am using btrfs directly over luks over block device.